# Desktop Bitcoin C# app question: on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Someone asked this question:

> Bitcoin payment API inside C# application
>
> I have never seen a bitcoin payment gateway API being implemented inside an c# application for example to unlock the application, have only seen that on websites. Does anyone have an example application which is using an btc API to unlock the app or process a payment for something else inside the app, without redirecting to a web page?

Subsequent comments:

> Actually I'd just prefer any finalized software where a btc payment gateway was implemented. But source code would be okay aswell
>
> you misunderstood my questions. I know all the API's. For example cryptopay C# payment gateway API. I am just looking for any application that has implementet the btc payment API.

Is it on-topic or off-topic?

Comment: Could you by chance provide all the comments, if this is the question I'm remembering correctly, I left a few there too.

Comment: There were many comments, I only copied the ones where the asker was adding actual new information.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question should be off-topic as it kind of circumvents the entire [No asking for Source Code rule](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/905/133).  Why does it matter what language the application is in? Also, there is really only one way to know what an application is written in, by looking at the source code of the application.  So, if the OP is asking for any application that has a Bitcoin Payment API in it and specifically is asking for the application to be in C#, he wants the source code.

For the question to be on-topic on this site, the OP should remove the C# requirement. It seems by his last comment:

> you misunderstood my questions. I know all the API's. For example cryptopay C# payment gateway API. I am just looking for **any application that has implementet the btc payment API**.

If you want any application, then you should be fine with any application written in any language.  Again, the only reason (unless I'm missing something) to have a requirement of "Must be written in C#" is to get the source code.  This then provides a circumvention around the rule that you can't ask for source code.  Currently (in my opinion), the question is off-topic until the C# requirement is removed because it shouldn't matter.

Comment: What are your thoughts about my "*only plausible explanation*" that I described in my answer?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Well, you said that, "the asker has reasons that we ignore". I do not think we should ignore any reason and especially this one. I believe the OP is asking for source code indirectly. I also think this question as it stands should be off-topic while you say, "I believe the question is not off-topic". Again, there is only one reason why he would specify a language. Why would he want to check the feasibility of such an implementation? If there's an API or Library that can do it, it's feasible and he's stated he's already aware of APIs.

Comment: Even if an API is available, "without redirecting to a web page" is important. See for instance gsutil, a command-line tool made by Google that awkwardly opens a web page for authentication, because even if an API exists, a web page detour is still needed.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Sure, I understand what you're saying, but I guess I'm just confused. The OP wants to see if it's possible to do it within the application, and then that's it?

Comment: I guess that's the only thing, yes. At least it is how I interpret the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is off-topic, because

- OP does not intend to use the software, and
- OP is not interested in *recommendations*.

Answers wouldn’t (have to) contain recommendations, they would just say:

> The tool Foo implements a BTC payment API, see line 2740 in the source code.

> The tool Bar makes use of a BTC payment API. After 3 days of gratis use, users have to pay 1 BTC to unlock it.

For OP, it doesn’t matter if the software is any good, if it has bugs, if it comes with malware, if its user interface makes sense, etc.  It doesn’t even matter what kind of software it is (it could be a media player, a browser, a text editor, …).

---

Related Meta discussion: [Is asking for sample, illustrative code on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/60)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why someone would require that the app is written in C# if they don't want the source code, but I guess the asker has reasons that we ignore. The only plausible explanation to me is that they want to check the feasibility of such an implementation. I will continue on this assumption.

The other requirements are:

- Desktop app
- Perform a particular Bitcoin operation within the app

Once again, the asker is probably thinking of implementing this, and wondering if it makes any sense at all, so they ask for an application that does the same thing, to check feasibility. I happened to be in the same situation when implementing OAuth in a desktop app, looking for example of apps that do this, to understand the workflow.

So, I believe the question is not off-topic. I let Bitcoin power users decide whether the question is too broad or not.

In any case, the asker should explain clearly why they need such an app, that would avoid misunderstandings. Also, they should remove the C# requirement as I believe it does not impact the purpose, and it strongly makes the question look off-topic.

Comment: Concur with it being at least "not off topic", probably outright on-topic. We shouldn't need to be questioning the motives behind questions to determine topicality.

Comment: @Undo I do not concur. OP doesn't want to use the software at all (which becomes clear by the fact that the only requirement is "uses Bitcoin" – features and quality are no arguments). It's rather like Tom and unor point out in their answers, a way to circumvent the "asking for source code examples" rule. Which is why I had closed the question (which then was deleted by Roomba). As Nicolas has reopened it, it's visible again – still with no answer. I'd recommend to close it again, as it is off-topic.